# Debugging on device with parallel installed app from store

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8.1

Can I debug my Windows Phone 8.1 App on a device where my productive app from store is installed? I don't wanna loose any data from my installed app, but I need for further development my Windows live account. From my understanding there should be a different ProductID for the Debugging app or not so there should be 2 apps with the same Name on my phone ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. I don't think a different ProductID is necessary. What you might do, but only for convenience, is give your app under development another name (I normally use [app name] DBG). That way you can distinguish your apps in the app list.

Comment: I will test it on my development phone which I have and will report about the results here. Does the VS changes the ProductID automatically when debugging an app on a device? Because from my understanding the ProductID is the unique key for an app on a phone.

Comment: An app gets a new ProductId during release [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769509(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_APPelement). So, your released app has another ProductId than the app under development.

Comment: OK, that was new to me but good to know. When I converted my app to 8.1 and published it after this i had a lot of trouble to copy and paste the GUIDs from the WMManifest.xml to the PackageManifest.xml file. But I tried to deploy the app on my phone and there was the message: Port is already used. First when I deinstalled the released app, debugging worked.

Comment: Another question: Have you changed anything else before debugging the app on a device where the released app is installed? Despite the name of the app, as you said.

Comment: No, I don't think so. By the way, I don't have any experience with Windows Phone 8.1 yet. I thought your question was about WP 8 because it is tagged as such.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Sorry. Yeah I will try today again, but I stil got the "already used Port" message. Will see. Thanks a lot.